# FOCUS and UNFOCUSSED in XAMARIN FORMS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have two text boxes namely T1 and T2.The validation is somewhat like, T1 can accept only values less than 10.

Lets say, the user enters 20 in T1. The focus is still on T1. Now the user taps on T2(Focus on T2).

What I need to do now is that, if the value in T1 is not less than 10. I need to remove the current value in T1(i.e 20) and set focus back to T1.

How do I achieve this in forms?

```
T2.Focused += (object sender, FocusEventArgs e) => {

            try {
                if (T1.text > 10) {
                    T1.Text = "";
                    T1.Focus ();
                }
            } catch {
                Console.WriteLine ("T2.Focused CAUGHT");
            }
        };
```

Comment: Could you post please your code snippet ?

Comment: The focus is just not going into T1. Focus from every where disappears and the numeric keyboard disappears.

Comment: `T1.text` is a string, how do you compare `T1.text > 10`?

Comment: Thats just a line... algo... @Rohit

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Focused](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Focused/) event :

```
T2.Focused += (s,e) => 
{
    if(int.Parse(T1.Text) > 10)
    {
        T1.Focus();
    }
}
```

But a better way will be to use the [Completed event](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/Xamarin.Forms.Entry.Completed/)

```
T1.Completed += (s,e) => 
{
    if(int.Parse(T1.Text) > 10)
    {
        T1.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: The T2.Focused event gets called fine, but the focus is not transferred to T1 and none of the text boxes have focus. The completed event is called only when i click on the done button in my device keyboard and not when i focus on another textbox. @Rohit

Comment: You can try running it on the UI thread to see if its not the background thread issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just try :

```
if (T1.Text <10)
{ 
T2.Select();
 }
else
{
T1.Clear();
 }
```